# Parsing error Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Getting a parsing error in javascript while deploying firebase functions... Its showing unexpected token which if i'm not mistaken means that there is an unexpected character somewhere... Stuck here for weeks now... Can somone help me out please

Code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}/`).onWrite((change, context) => {
        const user_id = context.params.user_id;
        const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

        console.log('We have a notification to send to ', user_id);

        if (!change.after.val()) {
            return console.log("A Notification has been deleted from the database", notification_id);
        }

        const fromUser = admin.database().ref('/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}').once('value');
        return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {
            const fromUserId = fromUserResult.val().from;
            console.log('You have a new notification from : ', from_user_id);

            const userQuery = admin.database().ref('UserData/${fromUserId}/name').once('value');
            return userQuery.then(userResult => {
                const userName = userResult.val();

                const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/UserData/${user_id}/TokenID`).once('value');
                return deviceToken.then(result => {

                    const token_id = result.val();

                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: '${userName}',
                            body: "You have recieved a new Message",
                            icon: "default",
                            click_action: "com.appmaster.akash.messageplus_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
                        },
                        data: {
                            from_user_id: fromUserId,
                            from_user_name: userName
                        }
                    };
                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
                        return console.log('This was the notofication Feature');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing two pairs of `})` at the end of the file. So:

```
...
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{
return console.log('This was the notofication Feature');
});
});
});
});
});
```

It is understandably impossible to see this with your current code.

The lack of indentation makes it incredibly hard to parse. That's why I passed the code through http://jsbeautifier.org/, which makes it much easier to parse.

I also recommend using a tool like https://eslint.org/demo/ to make it easier to find mistakes like this.

Comment: im sorry and i did format my code properly... and did add the }) according to your answer but now the same error for 48:12...

Comment: Oh wait u meant 2 pairs of brackets.. my bad... that solved it thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you'll still have few bugs in your code. on three places you're using single quote ' instead of back-tick `

```js
...
const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
...
const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`UserData/${fromUserId}/name`).once('value');
...
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `${userName}`,
    body: "You have recieved a new Message",
    icon: "default",
    click_action: "com.appmaster.akash.messageplus_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
  },
  data: {
    from_user_id: fromUserId,
    from_user_name: userName
  }
};
```

Comment: Im new to javascript and i have no idea what a backtick is... looks the same as single quote

Comment: back-tick is bit smaller and tilts to left, on most keyboards it's the key on the left to the number `1`. you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: But my code works with single quote itself... is it necessary to use backtick???

Comment: sorry for a late reply, code will work, but not as you expect it to work. for example if you use single(or double, it doesn't make any difference) quotes
`admin.database().ref('UserData/${fromUserId}/name').once('value');` this `${fromUserId}` will not get transformed into actual user ID that you expect to go there and you'll send invalid ref that will look like `'UserData/${fromUserId}/name'` instead of for example `'UserData/34/name'`
i hope you understand what I'm talking about :D